# Как после нажатия кнопки остановить цикл и сменить сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть бот который после нажатия кнопки выводит текст и файл .pdf после этого запускаеться бесконечный цикл который каждые 15 минут отсылает сообщение. Как сделать что б после нажатия любой кнопки или ввода команды /start цикл останавливался. И еще одна проблема, после нажатия кнопки 'main_menu' файл .pdf не пропадает и выдает ошибку there is no text in the message to edit. Как сделать что б файл пропал и появились другие кнопки?

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'cake')
def cake(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Order', callback_data='order'),
                                                         types.InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main_back'))
#Когда нажимаю main_back это сообщение остается и выводит ошибку
    bot.edit_message_text(message_id=call.message.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Choose a cake from the catalogChoose a cake from the catalog')
    bot.send_document(call.message.chat.id, open(r'1.pdf', 'rb'), reply_markup=markup)
    while True:
        sleep(15 * 60)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'You already chosen which cake you want to order?', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'main_back')
def main_back(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global information
    global photo
    global candy
    photo = False
    candy = False
    information.clear()
# Удаляет только документ с кнопками
    bot.delete_message(message_id=call.message.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
    bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Cake', callback_data='cake'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Bento-Cake', callback_data='bento_cake'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton('Candy', callback_data='candy'),
    )
    bot.edit_message_text(message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                          text='Choose what you want to order',
                          reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Она и не будет работать.  Колбек то не меняется

Comment: @oleksandrigo Как после нажатия кнопки сменить сообщение? У меня после нажатия  выводиться документ .pdf и кнопки, когда нажимаю кнопку назад в меню выводит ошибку что сообщение нельзя изменить edit_message_text не работает.

Comment: Просто удали сообщение и отправь новое. Некоторые сообщения нельзя редактировать как вам захочется

Comment: @oleksandrigo Через bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)? И куда его прописать если проверка на call.data не работает.

Comment: сделай новый хендлер...

Comment: @oleksandrigo Я сделал новый хендлер но проблема в том что одно сообщение остается и дальше выдает ошибку. И еще такой вопрос id сообщения надо менять при удалении? У других пользователей нормально будет работать?

Comment: Скиньте код, ибо я ничего не понял

Comment: @oleksandrigo Обновил

Comment: Зачем вам цикл?

Comment: Если бы это был aiogram я мог сказать бы как это должно было выглядеть, но в телеботе...

Comment: @oleksandrigo Что б в текущей сессии отправлять каждые 15 минут сообщение

Comment: Либо какой-нибудь schedule

Comment: @oleksandrigo Мне главное что б при нажатии кнопки main_back документ с текстом пропадал и выводил 3 кнопки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так?

```
bot.delete_message(message_id=call.message.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
bot.clear_step_handler_by_chat_id(chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Cake', callback_data='cake'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Bento-Cake', callback_data='bento_cake'),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton('Candy', callback_data='candy'))
bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                 text='Choose what you want to order',
                 reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Все работает только теперь другая проблема когда первый раз нажимаем кнопку 'main_back' то все работает отлично но когда снова переходим по кнопке cake -> main_back кнопка перестает работает то есть она работает только один раз, дальше нужно перезапускать бота c чем это связано?

Comment: @Kanashii12 с бесконечным циклом